# What can I do if I face conflicts with my supervisor?

Tags: advisor, supervision, conflict-of-interest

I am an international Ph.D. student in Canada. I have many conflicts with my supervisor and I really don't enjoy working under his supervision and I prefer to change my supervisor. However, the problem is that he has much power in our department and I guess that no other prof. will be willing to support me. If I ask the department to change my supervisor and they do not accept my request, it will be a nightmare. If they accept, I may still face some problems.
I would be thankful to know what I can and should do.

I should state that I don't wanna be in a situation that either university forces me to leave or I choose it.

Comment: At my university, there is a powerful Head of Students -- an academic staff. His/her role is look after the wellbeing of students.  He/she should have a solution for you.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus: Your Head of Students should be looking out for OP? Or are you sure the OP has auch a powerful person?

Comment: Is there anyone in the department with whom you could discuss this confidentially? A second supervisor? A PhD tutor? Just another staff member whom you trust if there is no official role for this kind of thing? (I'm not in Canada, where I am there are people officially assigned to such roles.)

Comment: To begin with, do you understand just why you do not enjoy working under the particular person? What have you done to try and change the situation?

Comment: I have not talked with other profs. because I believe if my current supervisor knows it, there might be some troubles for me. 
For example, he forces me to work on a topic that I am not interested in. He says you should work on a topic that you enjoy, but it is just in speaking, and in reality, he tries to force me to work on his favorite topics. 
He does not respect students (even my friends agree with me). For example, in his emails, he NEVER says hello.

Comment: @user111388 Yes.  We do.  Our university has very robust policies that protect students.